# Running other modules' submodules

Tags: module, racket

I'd like to selectively run a Racket module's submodules from another module. Please help me fill in the blanks!

**File 1**

```
#lang racket/base

;; <big file, lots of code>

(module+ small-tests
   ;; basic correctness checks
   (displayln "Small tests pass!")
)

(module+ big-tests
   ;; heavy duty stress tests
   (displayln "Big tests pass!")
)
```

**File 2**

```
#lang racket/base

(module+ main
  ;; Trigger either the small-tests or the big-tests,
  ;; depending on what's written here.
  (require '???)
)
```

It would also be great if running the big tests would automatically run the small tests, too.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what specifically you're having trouble with, but could [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29) help here?

Comment: If you just want to know the syntax for requiring a submodule, it's just [`submod`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=submod#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._submod%29%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Leif and Alexis's hints, the way to get  **File 2** to run the small-tests submodule is to replace the `'???` with:

```
(submod "file1.rkt" small-tests)
```

Also, editing the `big-tests` submodule to include the line:

```
(require (submod ".." small-tests))
```

will cause both small & big tests to run when **File 2** executes `(require (submod "file1.rkt" big-tests))`.

Comment: Tip: Although that's fine for plain `require`, you'll find that `(dynamic-require '(submod ".." foo) #f)` errors with `standard-module-name-resolver: no base path for relative submodule path: (submod ".." bar)`. Use `quote-module-path` from `syntax/location`: `(dynamic-require (quote-module-path ".." bar) #f)`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`submod`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=submod#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._submod%29%29) form is used to require a module's submodule.

As an example:

```
#lang racket

(module A racket
  (module+ main
    (displayln "Hello World")))

(module B racket
  (require (submod ".." A main)))

(require 'B)
```